# Windows Store App Development - InvalidateRequerySuggested

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, ivalueconverter

in regular WPF projects I've used

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

in order to force a value converter to be executed again.

Now, in Windows Store App development this handy command is no longer available.
Does an equivalent command or something else, which does the trick, exist?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: To force a value converter to be executed? Shouldn't you invalidate the property in question then? I used CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested to invalidate command CanExecute status whenever I needed to not to run value converters again. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The value converter was just another place I wanted to invalidate as well.

Comment: In case of updating commands I think you have to roll that functionality yourself in Windows store apps. Basically the old commands delegated the can execute change event to RequerySuggested event. It's possible to do something simmilar oneself.

Comment: I also fear that this nice and handy command has to be reimplemented manually. Thanks for confirming my impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CommandManager` doesn't exist in WinRT. You need to manually refresh listeners. Here's my example implementation of `DelegateCommand<T>` that illustrates this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> m_executeAction;
    private readonly Predicate<T> m_canExecutePredicate;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeAction)
        : this(executeAction, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeAction, Predicate<T> canExecutePredicate)
    {
        if (executeAction == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeAction");
        }

        m_executeAction = executeAction;
        m_canExecutePredicate = canExecutePredicate;
    }

    public event EventHandler Executed;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute((T)parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(T parameter)
    {
        var result = true;
        var canExecutePredicate = m_canExecutePredicate;
        if (canExecutePredicate != null)
        {
            result = canExecutePredicate(parameter);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void Execute(T parameter)
    {
        m_executeAction(parameter);
        RaiseExecuted();
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseExecuted()
    {
        var handler = Executed;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

The WPF version of this class indirectly uses `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` by implementing `CanExecuteChanged` as follows:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

However, in WinRT this is not supported and in my WinRT version any code that invalidates the state of the delegate command must call the `Refresh` method to cause bound items in the view to requery the command.

I think the best solution to your specific problem would be to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your view model. Invoking the `PropertyChanged` event on this interface is equivalent to my `Refresh` method and forces bound elements in the view to re-evaluate themselves and, thus, to re-run all associated `IValueConverter` instances.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft Developer Network it does work with Windows 8 and Framework 4.5.  However, it does state the following:

> The CommandManager only pays attention to certain conditions in
>   determining when the command target has changed, such as change in
>   keyboard focus. In situations where the CommandManager does not
>   sufficiently determine a change in conditions that cause a command to
>   not be able to execute, InvalidateRequerySuggested can be called to
>   force the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event.

But since it doesn't mention Windows Mobile for Windows Devices below WinRT being compliant that above command may not work for those devices, but if it is for Windows Store for WinRT and Windows 8 it should work just fine.

If I misunderstood your question please let me know and I'll try to assist further.

[Article about command here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Greg. But the sad thing is that you cannot even reference the PresentationCore.dll / use the System.Windows.Input namespace as they are not compatible with Windows Store projects.

Comment: Really that seems odd. Ill test that later see what I come up with